# Error using Http JSON AngularJS 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use the following code after trying several ways online tutorials I can not make it work.

```
..//
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({

    viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],

    template: `
    ..//
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 well">

        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block"
        (click)="get()" value="Fetch Users">

        <hr>
        <ul>
           <li *ngFor="#user of users">
             Id: {{ user.name }} | Name: {{ user.name }} | JSON: {{ user | json }}
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    ..//

export class Mov {

    //Inicio test http

    users: Array<Object>;
    http: any;

    //
    //constructor(@Inject(HttpFactory) http) {
    //constructor(http: Http) {
    constructor(http: Http){
         //
        this.http = http;
    }

    get(){
        this.http('resources/users.json')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(users => this.users = users);
    }
```

obtain this error:

> EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
>
> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.http is not a function

anyone can tell me I'm doing wrong, I'm sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as the error message states `this.http` is not a function, it's an object which has several methods. You need `this.http.get()` method:

```
this.http.get('resources/users.json')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(users => this.users = users);
```

Comment: this solves the problem, thanks, but I think also the response @PankajParkar

Comment: I have no idea what to accept, I think the two helped with the error.

Comment: I tried, as was the code unchanged, as published and your answer is the solution

Comment: Yea, dilemma, feel free to accept whatever you you want, it's fine :)

Answer (score 3):

Seems like somehow `Http` isn't get injected correctly. Use `@Inject` to inject `Http` dependency.

```
import { Component, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
//above code should be at start.

constructor(@Inject(Http) http: Http) {
```

`@Inject` is needed for acquiring dependency when not using Typescript for transpilation of JS.

Comment: Maybe I doing something wrong that I add this import {Inject} from 'angular2/core'; and constructor(@Inject(Http) http: Http){ and obtain equal error

Comment: @AngelAngel may I know which angular2 version you are using?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.3",

Comment: @AngelAngel have you added `rx.js`, you need to add `rxjs/add/operators/map` because you are using `map` operator

Comment: I have -> import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; this refers to that? in this file

Comment: I have no idea what to accept, I think the two helped with the error.

Comment: I tried, as was the code unchanged, as published and @dfsq answer is the solution Thanks for your time