# `this` is undefined in Angular filter function used by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, this, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to filter an an array in the dom that uses ng-repeat. The filter works when I hard code the return, but when I try to use `this`, it gives me the error

> Cannot read property minHeight of undefined.

So for some reason this is undefined, but it works in other functions in the controller. I'm not sure why it doesn't work in the filter.

I'm sure I'm missing something ridiculously simple, but I cannot find it

**Controller**

```
export class ItemComponent {

    /*@ngInject*/
    constructor($http) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.minHeight = 0;
    }

   filter(row){
       console.log(this.minHeight);
       return row.minHeight > this.minHeight;
   }
```

**HTML**

```
ng-repeat="item in itemCtrl.items | filter: itemCtrl.filter"
```

**Transpiled Code (from app.bundle.js in browser)**

```
var ItemsComponent = exports.ItemsComponent = function () {
  /*@ngInject*/
  ItemsComponent.$inject = ['$http'];
  function ItemsComponent($http) {
    _classCallCheck(this, ItemsComponent);

    this.$http = $http;
    this.minHeight = 0;
  }

  _createClass(ItemsComponent, [{
    key: '$onInit',
    value: function $onInit() {
      this.loadItems();
    }
  }, {
    key: 'loaditems',
    value: function loadItems() {
      var _this = this;

      this.$http.get('/api/items').then(function (res) {
        _this.items = res.data;
        console.log(_this.items);
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
  }, {
    key: 'filter',
    value: function filter(row) {
      console.log(this.minHeight);

      return row.minHeight > 3;
    }
  }]);

  return ItemsComponent;
}();
```

Comment: How does the transpiled code looks like?

Comment: It looks exactly the same. Nothing is being minified.

Comment: Hmm, pure es6 so, could you please provide a fiddle reproducing the error, I tested by my self and it worked normally.

Comment: I was actually wrong, adding the transpiled code now. You can see that this isn't in it

Comment: I've tested the transpiled code as well, and it does'n reproduce the error. What about the fiddle reproducing the error?

Comment: I don't have a fiddle reproducing the error right now. How are you testing it? What could the differences be?

Comment: By just running your function manually with the arguments. But the problem can be other thing that we can't reproduce without the original scenario.

Comment: try this plnkr:  [Angular2 plunkr with http injectable - Mahesh](http://plnkr.co/edit/ADFdawFVTrxjJl1oMzO9?p=preview)  This uses '@'injectable and '@'inject, in case you are not using a transcript compiler.  Also refer [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370405/angular-2-http-cannot-resolve-all-parameters-for-appservice)

Comment: Thanks, not using Angular2 though. The big difference I see is that this appears in the transpiled functions that work: **var _this = this;** but it does not show up in the functions that do not.

Comment: It has to do with itemCtrl.filter in the dom. When I call the function in the $onIt in the controller, it finds this.

Comment: When I change the dom to use **itemCtrl.filter()**, the function finds this, but it doesn't pass the data from the ng-repeat array

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is not the best approach, but since there is no answer and I could solve my problem this way, I will share it with you.

There is no `this` context in the filter function when called on `ng-repeat` (why?), so I solved it binding the context and getting the controller context from the `this` context.

### HTML

```
ng-repeat="item in itemCtrl.items | filter: itemCtrl.filter.bind(this)"
```

### Controller

```
filter(row) {
  console.log(this.itemCtrl.minHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you figured this out, but if you didn't want to bind in the template file, and I prefer to put as little as possible in the template file, you could bind in your class definition in the constructor.

For example:

```
export class ItemComponent {
    /*@ngInject*/
    constructor($http) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.minHeight = 0;

        // arrow function will bind the 'this' you need, or you could use '.bind' instead
        this.filter = (row) => {
            console.log(this.minHeight);
            return row.minHeight > this.minHeight;
       }
    }
```