# Angular 2 Unhandled Promise rejection: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for FooService: (?) - how to fix without using @Inject everywhere?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, systemjs, typescript2.0

when I run "npm run start" I get this error in the browser's console:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for RestClientService: (?).
>       Error: Can't resolve all parameters for RestClientService: (?).

Here is the relevant code from that class:

```
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

import { extractData, handleError } from "./helpers";
import { Notification, Slide, Spot } from "./models";
import "./rxjs-operators";

@Injectable()
export class RestClientService {
    constructor (private http: Http) {}
// methods in the class
}
```

I tried the solution here:
[Angular 2 HTTP "Cannot resolve all parameters for 'AppService'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370405/angular-2-http-cannot-resolve-all-parameters-for-appservice)

At that point, my RestClientService had a constructor that looked like this:

```
constructor (@Inject(Http) private http: Http) {}
```

So that DID help get rid of the error for that class, however now pretty much all my other classes are having the same problem.

**HOW CAN I AVOID HAVING TO USE @Inject EVERYWHERE?**

Here's what I hope is relevant:

package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "my broken app",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" \"npm run generate-css\" \"npm run watch-css\" ",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "generate-css": "node-sass -r app --output ./generated-css",
    "watch-css": "node-sass -w -r app --output ./generated-css",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "license": "",
  "author": "me",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.3.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "mydatepicker": "0.0.36",
    "ng2-translate": "^4.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "socket.io": "^1.4.8",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.4.8",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.43",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^2.53.33",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.25",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "live-server": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
            'ng2-translate':             'npm:ng2-translate/bundles',
            'lodash':                    'npm:lodash',
            'socket.io-client':          'npm:socket.io-client/socket.io.js',
            'mydatepicker':              'npm:mydatepicker'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'ng2-translate': {
                main: 'ng2-translate',
                defaultExtension: 'umd.js'
            },
            'socket.io-client': {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'mydatepicker': {
                main: './dist/index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            lodash: {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpModule }     from "@angular/http";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { DashboardComponent } from "./components/dashboard/dashboard.component";
import { AcquisitionComponent } from "./components/acquisition/acquisition.component";
import { AlarmsAlertsService } from "./shared/notification-manager.service";
import { AuditService, Logger } from "./shared/log.service";
import { AuthGuard } from "./shared/auth-guard.service";
import { AuthService } from "./shared/auth.service";
import { ConfigurationComponent } from "./components/configuration/configuration.component";
import { ConfirmService } from "./shared/confirm/confirm.service";
import { PopOverComponent } from "./shared/pop-over/pop-over.component";
import { InstrumentStatusService } from "./shared/notification-manager.service";
import { LoginComponent } from "./components/login/login.component";
import { ReportsComponent } from "./components/reports/reports.component";
import { routing } from "./app.routing";
import { MyDatePickerModule } from "mydatepicker/dist/my-date-picker.module";
import { MyDatePicker } from "./shared/date-picker/my-date-picker.component";
import { RestClientService } from "./shared/rest-client.service";
import { SearchComponent } from "./components/search/search.component";
import { SupervisionComponent } from "./components/supervision/supervision.component";
import { TranslateModule } from "ng2-translate";
import { HelpComponent } from "./components/help/help.component";
import { ConfirmComponent } from "./shared/confirm/confirm.component";
import { InteractiveSlideComponent } from "./components/interactive-slide/interactive-slide.component";
import { SlidesTableComponent } from "./components/slides-table/slides-table.component";
import { SoundBarComponent } from "./components/sound-bar/sound-bar.component";
import { VolumeControlComponent } from "./components/volume-control/volume-control.component";
import { SortArrowsComponent } from "./components/sort-arrows/sort-arrows.component";
import { NotificationsTableComponent } from "./components/notifications-table/notifications-table.component";
import { StatusIndicatorComponent } from "./components/status-indicator/component-status-indicator.component";
import { TabComponent } from "./components/tab/tab.component";
import { TabsComponent } from "./components/tabs/tabs.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        MyDatePickerModule,
        routing,
        TranslateModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [
        AuditService,
        AlarmsAlertsService,
        AuthGuard,
        AuthService,
        ConfirmService,
        InstrumentStatusService,
        Logger,
        RestClientService
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        AcquisitionComponent,
        ConfigurationComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        ReportsComponent,
        SearchComponent,
        SupervisionComponent
    ],
    declarations: [
        AcquisitionComponent,
        ConfigurationComponent,
        ConfirmComponent,
        MyDatePicker,
        PopOverComponent,
        DashboardComponent,
        HelpComponent,
        InteractiveSlideComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        NotificationsTableComponent,
        ReportsComponent,
        SearchComponent,
        SlidesTableComponent,
        SortArrowsComponent,
        SoundBarComponent,
        StatusIndicatorComponent,
        SupervisionComponent,
        TabComponent,
        TabsComponent,
        VolumeControlComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [ DashboardComponent ],
    schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And here is an example of the RestClientService in use:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { RestClientService } from "./rest-client.service";
import { Slide, Spot } from "./models";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import * as _ from "lodash";

@Injectable()
export class DataManagerService {
    sysInfo;
    dataHandle: Observable<any>;
    errorMessage;
    sysInfoArray = [];
    currentlySelectedSlide: Slide = null;
    currentSlides: Slide[];
    foundSlides: Observable<Slide[]>;
    currentExports: Object[];
    foundExports: Observable<Object[]>;
    currentSpotImages: Object[];
    foundSpotImages: Observable<Object[]>;
    removeExportCall: Observable<any>;

    constructor(private rest: RestClientService, private authService: AuthService) {}

    initSysInfo() {
        // get and process the current alarms from the database
        this.dataHandle = this.rest.getSysInfo();
        this.dataHandle.subscribe(
            data => {
                this.sysInfo = data;
            },
            error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
   // more code here
}
```

Please let me know if you need to see any other files.  Clearly, I'm not sure where the problem might be.

Comment: Could you also share code where this RestClientService  is being used?

Comment: alright, I just added an example of the RestClientService being used in a service that calls the service's "getSysInfo" method.

Comment: Just a follow-up to this question: eventually I bit the bullet and just went through and put Inject statements everywhere.  This can't be right, but it got the app up and running so I can continue development.  If anyone knows how to accomplish this feat without Inject, I'd still love to know, but it's not as time sensitive.